# Selecting one of 2 template functions for 4 types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is there a cleaner ("less c++11") way of selecting which template function to use in this example, based on multiple types. I only want to have 2 functions, I could overload or call implementations with an extra 2 or 4 functions.

```
struct A{}; struct B{}; struct C{}; struct D{};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, A>::value or std::is_same<T, B>::value, void>::type
foo(T& t)
{ 
    printf("first\n"); 
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, C>::value or std::is_same<T, D>::value, void>::type
foo(T& t)
{ 
    printf("second\n"); 
}

int main()
{
  A a; B b; C c; D d;
  foo(a); foo(b); foo(c); foo(d);
}
```

Comment: No, was being explicit, updated the question.

Comment: You can create a traits to shorten the `or` (to check if `T` is in typelist {`A`, `B`}), but it would be more c++11.

Comment: [This is an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the on you're asking about, but the problem whose solution you believe is what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> less c++11

The code below works according with the revision C++98.
It simulates the more *C++11-ish* `std::enable_if`, nothing more.

```
#include<cstdio>

struct A{}; struct B{}; struct C{}; struct D{};

template<typename> struct R1;
template<> struct R1<A> { typedef void type; };
template<> struct R1<B> { typedef void type; };

template<typename> struct R2;
template<> struct R2<C> { typedef void type; };
template<> struct R2<D> { typedef void type; };

template <typename T>
typename R1<T>::type foo(T& t)
{ 
    printf("first\n"); 
}

template <typename T>
typename R2<T>::type foo(T& t)
{ 
    printf("second\n"); 
}

int main()
{
    A a; B b; C c; D d;
    foo(a); foo(b); foo(c); foo(d);
}
```

> cleaner

To be honest I find C++11 cleaner, with its `using` declarations and `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 2):

There is the overload way:

```
void foo(A& a) { printf("first\n"); }
void foo(B& b) { printf("first\n"); }
void foo(C& c) { printf("second\n"); }
void foo(D& d) { printf("second\n"); }
```

or to avoid code duplication

```
template <typename T> void print_first(T&) { printf("first\n"); }
template <typename T> void print_second(T&) { printf("second\n"); }

void foo(A& a) { print_first(a); }
void foo(B& b) { print_first(b); }
void foo(C& c) { print_second(c); }
void foo(D& d) { print_second(d); }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned, I only want 2 functions, Updated the question.

Comment: @Salgar What's wrong with 4 functions? If you want to avoid code duplication, you can make 2 templated functions and make the overloads call one of those function.

Comment: That's 6 functions, that sounds like much more code than I have above?

Comment: but without "complicated" `std::enable_if` and *traits*.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just make use of inheritance e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t>
struct tag {};

struct A: tag<1>{ }; struct B: tag<1>{ };
struct C: tag<2>{ }; struct D: tag<2>{ };

void foo(tag<1>&) {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

void foo(tag<2>&) {
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   A a; B b; C c; D d;
   foo(a);  foo(b); foo(c); foo(d);
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
2
```